# Compatibility (as Spring boot Maven dependencies) between Elasticsearch 7.17, spring data elasticsearch and elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client

Tags: spring-boot, maven, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have an Spring Boot + Elasticsearch application that had the now deprecated High Level Rest Client. I am trying to migrate the existing queries/methods to the new Java API Client but want to keep the HLRC for a bit (in case I break anything).

I seem to be running into a dependency problem that I'm not getting. I am currently getting the error `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/elasticsearch/xcontent/ToXContentObject` which I assume is due to compatibility issues. These are my current (relevent) dependencies:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
            <version>7.17.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.json-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.4</version>
        </dependency>
```

The Elasticsearch is on 7.17 . As for the maven dependencies... I don't really know what versions to use so that it can run the old HLRC still while I test out newer code? (So I set the versions to the newest possible ones)

Edit infos:

- current spring boot version is 2.2.8
- before manually setting the version, org.elasticsearch.client was on 6.8.x
- is my approach dumb and I should just scrap all the HLRC in favor of implementing/testing Java API Client?

Any pointers/fixes appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correctly it was in version 7.15 or 7.16 that Elasticsearch had a breaking change moving the xcontent classes to a different package. You cannot use Spring Data Elasticsearch 4.3.x with Elasticsearch 7.17

Comment: oh nooo~ I've read something like this elsewhere as well, but I couldn't find out more if Spring Data Elasticsearch will be available in later versions... I'll assume it's not possible and just restructure I guess? Thanks for the confirmation!

Comment: I'm using client 6.8 and server version 7.14.2. My search query with a term query returns zero hits. Any suggestions on this part?